# Total of products entered and total of all products entered using Switch

Tags: java

I am trying to get my output to show the total cost of each item entered and a grand total of the cost of all items, the program runs but when I try to use the end-of-file indicator nothing happens, what am I missing?

```
package switch1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switch1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total = 0;
        int productCounter = 0;
        int aProduct = 0;
        int bProduct = 0;
        int cProduct = 0;
        int dProduct = 0;
        int eProduct = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n    %s%n    %s%n",
                "Select your product(1=bread, 2=cheese, 3=meat, 4=msutard, 5=mayo)",
                "Type the end-of-file indicator to terminate input:",
                "On UNIX/Linux/macOS type <Ctrl> d then press Enter",
                "On Windows type <Ctrl> z then press Enter");

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int product = input.nextInt();
            total += product;
            ++productCounter;

            switch (product) {
                case 1:
                    ++aProduct;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ++bProduct;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ++cProduct;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ++dProduct;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ++eProduct;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%nProduct Selection:%n");

        if (productCounter != 0) {
            double aTotal = (aProduct * 1.89);
            double bTotal = (bProduct * 3.99);
            double cTotal = (cProduct * 6.99);
            double dTotal = (dProduct * 1.99);
            double eTotal = (eProduct * 2.99);
            total = (((double)aProduct * 1.89) + ((double)bProduct * 3.99) + ((double)cProduct * 6.99) + ((double)dProduct * 1.99) + ((double)eProduct * 2.99));

            System.out.printf("You ordered %d gallons of milk totaling: %f%n", aProduct, aTotal);
            System.out.printf("You ordered %d loaves of bread totaling: %f%n", bProduct, bTotal);
            System.out.printf("You ordered %d packages of cheese totaling: %f%n", cProduct, cTotal);
            System.out.printf("You ordered %d pounds of meat totaling: %f%n", dProduct, dTotal);
            System.out.printf("You ordered %d bottles of mustard totaling: %f%n", eProduct, eTotal);
            System.out.printf("Your total grocery bill is: %d%n", total);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No products were entered");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `\n` instead of `%n` in your `printf()` statements?

Comment: @dave No. `%n` is **correct**. Do you mean **end of file**? Are you then pressing enter?

Comment: Learn something every day: `%n` is platform-safe version of `\n`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes I was referring to end of file, and yes I would then press enter and nothing would happen.  I've even tried typing in <ctrl> z and get the same error message

Comment: @E.Peterson *and get the same error message* What error message is that?

Comment: @E.Peterson Ok. I ran your code. `System.out.printf("Your total grocery bill is: %f%n", total);` (you have a **typo**). Next time, **please** include relevant details like that in your question. Oh, and `total = aTotal + bTotal + cTotal + dTotal + eTotal;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace scanner.hasNext with scanner.hasNextLine. If you're on a newline and you hit CTRL-D (linux) or CTRL-Z (Windows), hasNextLine should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better question is "how do I find out what am I doing wrong? "
One step would be to warp you code in a `try-catch` block like:

```
        try {   
            //the code goes here 
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And see the exceptions.
It will indicate a problem in this line

```
System.out.printf("Your total grocery bill is: %d%n", total);
```